# C++ Address Book Array and Textfile

Tags: c++

Sorry for the lack of previous explanation to my school's assignment. Here's what I'm working with and what I have / think I have to do.

I have the basic structure for populating the address book inside an array, however, the logic behind populating a text file is a bit beyond my knowledge. I've researched a few examples, however, the implementation is a bit tricky due to my novice programming ability.

I've gone through some code that looks relevant in regard to my requirements:

```
ifstream input("addressbook.txt"); 
ofstream out("addressbook.txt");
```

For ifstream, I believe implementing this into the voidAddBook::AddEntry() would work, though I've tried it and the code failed to compile, for multiple reasons.

For ostream, I'm lost and unsure as to how I can implement this correctly. I understand basic file input and output into a text file, however, this method is a bit more advanced and hence why I'm resorting to stackoverflow's guidance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> //Required to use string compare                         

using namespace std;

class AddBook{

public:
    AddBook()
      {
         count=0;
      }

   void AddEntry();
   void DispAll();
   void DispEntry(int i); // Displays one entry                              
   void SearchLast();

   int Menu();

   struct EntryStruct
   {
      char FirstName[15];
      char LastName[15];
      char Birthday[15];
      char PhoneNum[15];
      char Email[15];
   };

   EntryStruct entries[100];
   int count;
};


void AddBook::AddEntry()
{

   cout << "Enter First Name: ";
   cin >> entries[count].FirstName;

   cout << "Enter Last Name: ";
   cin >> entries[count].LastName;

   cout << "Enter Date of Birth: ";
   cin >> entries[count].Birthday;

    cout << "Enter Phone Number: ";
   cin >> entries[count].PhoneNum;

   cout << "Enter Email: ";
   cin >> entries[count].Email;

   ++count;                                                
}


void AddBook::DispEntry(int i)
{                
   cout << "First name : " << entries[i].FirstName << endl;
   cout << "Last name : " << entries[i].LastName << endl;
   cout << "Date of birth : " << entries[i].Birthday << endl;
   cout << "Phone number : " << entries[i].PhoneNum << endl;
   cout << "Email: " << entries[i].Email << endl;
}

void AddBook::DispAll()
{
   cout << "Number of entries : " << count << endl;

   for(int i = 0;i < count;++i)
      DispEntry(i);
}

void AddBook::SearchLast()
{
   char lastname[32];
   cout << "Enter last name : ";
   cin >> lastname;

   for(int i = 0;i < count;++i)
   {
      if(strcmp(lastname, entries[i].LastName) == 0)
      {
         cout << "Found ";
         DispEntry(i);
         cout << endl;
      }
   }
}

AddBook AddressBook;

int Menu()
{
   int num;
   bool BoolQuit = false;

   while(BoolQuit == false)
   {                     

      cout << "Address Book Menu" << endl;
      cout << "(1) Add A New Contact" << endl;
      cout << "(2) Search By Last Name" << endl;
      cout << "(3) Show Complete List" << endl;
      cout << "(4) Exit And Save" << endl;
      cout << endl;

        cout << "Please enter your selection (1-4) and press enter: ";      
      cin >> num;
      cout << endl;

      if (num == 1)
         AddressBook.AddEntry();
      else if (num == 2)
         AddressBook.SearchLast();
      else if (num == 3)
         AddressBook.DispAll();
      else if (num == 4)
         BoolQuit = true;
      else
         cout << "Please enter a number (1-4) and press enter: " << endl;

      cout << endl;                                                            
   }

   return 0;
}

int main (){
   Menu();

   return 0;
}
```

As it currently stands, I'm still stuck. Here's where I believe I should start:

```
cout << "Please enter your selection (1-4) and press enter: ";      
      cin >> num;
      cout << endl;

      if (num == 1)
         AddressBook.AddEntry();
      else if (num == 2)
         AddressBook.SearchLast();
      else if (num == 3)
         AddressBook.DispAll();
      else if (num == 4)
         BoolQuit = true;
      //save first name
      //save last name
      //save dob
      //save phone number
      //save email
      //exit
      else
         cout << "Please enter a number (1-4) and press enter: " << endl;

      cout << endl;                                                            
   }
```

Somehow, during menu option 4 the array should dump the data into a .txt file and arrange it in a way that it can be easily imported upon reloading the program. I'm a little confused as to how I can store the array data from each character array into a .txt file.

Comment: What exactly is your question? We're not obligated to cater to the requests of those who don't have a specific objective in mind. We're also not obligated to help those who don't try themselves.

Comment: Fixed my question. I apologize for the lack of clarity and effort from the previous.

Comment: Updated question with current status.

Comment: Okay, I will assist you as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll update as I can if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, if the input is coming from the file `input`, then instead of doing `cin >> x` you would have to do `input >> x`. If it's coming from standard input (the keyboard), then you can use `cin`.

Also, your `else if` statement should be something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    // ...
    else if (num == 4)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < AddressBook.count; ++i)
        {
            AddBook::EntryStruct data = AddressBook.entries[i];

            out << data.FirstName << " " << data.LastName
                                  << std::endl
                << data.Birthday  << std::endl
                << data.PhoneNum  << std::endl
                << data.Email;
        }
    }
    break;
}
```